# Combine string in a column based on groups in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas DataFrame, DF:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | red | Texas |
| Apple | red | California |
| Banana | yellow | Indiana |
| Banana | yellow | Florida |

I would like to get it in a dictionary in the form:

`{ "Apple red" : ['Texas', 'California'], "Banana yellow" : ['Indiana', 'Florida'] }`

where Key = concatenation of strings in column A and column B (and)

Value = all corresponding strings from column C (based on groupby) in a list.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

Key Note: It should also work if there are more than 3 columns to be grouped for dictionary's key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = dict(
    df.groupby(df["Column A"] + " " + df["Column B"])["Column C"].agg(list)
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Apple red': ['Texas', 'California'], 'Banana yellow': ['Indiana', 'Florida']}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just made an last minute edit to the post. It should also work if there are multiple columns in the DF to be grouped for the dictionary's key.

Comment: @Krishna If they are strings then just concatenate the columns together: `df.groupby(df["Column A"] + " " + df["Column B"] + " " + df['Column X'] + ...etc)`

Answer (score 1):

One option, which should be performant as well, is with a default dictionary:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for a, b, c in zip(df['Column A'], df['Column B'], df['Column C']):
    key = a + " " + b
    out[key].append(c)

out
defaultdict(list,
            {'Apple red': ['Texas', 'California'],
             'Banana yellow': ['Indiana', 'Florida']})
```